# Google map's turn by turn gps navigation for ios development

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios6, ios7, google-maps-sdk-ios

My app required to include turn by turn gps navigation. Can anybody tell how to integrate google map for turn by turn gps navigation.

I can found it in android development. But i can't found navigation from google map's iOS development documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro

Please anybody help to resolve my problem.

Comment: please provide navigation api link for android

Comment: @PK86 You can get google navigation api  for android once you search.

Comment: @PK86 here we discussing about ios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The google map ios Sdk does not have any turn-by-turn navigation api or navigation api's,yet.

Please refer link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme for custom url schema features.

Comment: Can we show in our app? same like google map navigation?

Answer (score 3):

Please see our [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), specifically 10.2.c.i.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but the answer given in the Google Maps Terms of Service that Brett pointed you to is 'NO'.   You can't just dress up Google Maps in an Apple logo and call it a day.