# Google map's turn by turnGPS In app-navigation for iOS development

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

my app required to include turn by turn GPS navigation same as OLA, UBER, and taxi hire application. I have used the Google Direction API for showing path and duration. I have checked the following links but not helpful to me.

[gps navigation for ios development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382792/google-maps-turn-by-turn-gps-navigation-for-ios-development),

[Turn-By-Turn navigation using Google Map SDK and Swift in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723834/turn-by-turn-navigation-using-google-map-sdk-and-swift-in-ios-app)

Is it possible to use Google Maps inside an iOS application. Please share your thoughts and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Google has a Navigation SDK that was mentioned in I/0 18: https://youtu.be/XVjyIA3f_Ic?t=20m48s. However, I'm afraid this SDK is currently available only for ride sharing companies like Uber, Ola or Lyft.

Comment: Hey @xomena, Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

According to the second link you posted, it's not not allowed to have turn-by-turn navigation using the Google Maps API. In any case, have a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro

Comment: Abby, Thanks for your reply, Have you used this for before?